# SQL Select inner join with multiple value

Tags: sql, select, left-join, inner-join

How should I write the select statement with the following table? where ID can refer to either province or city.

CANADA Table:

| canada_id | name | id | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Canada | 33 | 0 |
| 2 (Province) | Alberta | 1100 | 33 |
| 3 (Province) | British Columbia | 1200 | 33 |
| 4 (city) | Banff | 1101 | 1100 |
| 5 (city) | Calgary | 1102 | 1100 |
| 6 (city) | Victory | 1201 | 1200 |
| 7 (city) | Vancouver | 1202 | 1200 |

CLIENT Table:

| client_id | name | province_id | city_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 1100 | 1102 |
| 2 | Kitty | 1200 | 1201 |

I would like to return:

| name | province_id | province_name | city_id | city_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1100 | Alberta | 1102 | Calgery |

Comment: [mre] [ask] [Help] Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    CLIENT.name,
    CLIENT.province_id, CANADA_province.name as province_name,
    CLIENT.city_id, CANADA_city.name as city_name
FROM CLIENT
    LEFT JOIN CANADA as CANADA_province
        ON CLIENT.province_id = CANADA_province.id
    LEFT JOIN CANADA as CANADA_city
        ON CLIENT.city_id = CANADA_city.id
WHERE CLIENT.name = 1;
```

If you want to get the "Full Client List", simply remove

```
WHERE CLIENT.name = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CLIENT.name,
       CLIENT.province_id, CANADA_province.name as province_name,
       CLIENT.city_id,     CANADA_city.name as city_name
FROM CLIENT
INNER JOIN CANADA as CANADA_province
    ON CLIENT.province_id = CANADA_province.id
INNER JOIN CANADA as CANADA_city
    ON CLIENT.city_id = CANADA_city.id
WHERE CLIENT.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thank for your solution, it works like a charm.
But what if I "city" is NULL? can i still get the full "client" list?